Gekko results is not correct with using gekko_nn_tf
I created a quarter-car model in Gekko in which the damper force is modelled with an ANN network.
To compare the results, I solved this problem with a non-linear damper (ANN) and a linear damper with Scipy and Gekko. However, the Gekko solution is not correct in the case of a non-linear problem.
Links for ANN Keras Model and trial_1.csv
Gekko model:
m_s = 400
m_u = 47.75
k_t = 239e3
k = 22e3
c = 2300
linear_damper = True
m = GEKKO()
m.time = np.linspace(0,5,100)
x0 = m.Var(value=0)
x1 = m.Var(value=0)
x2 = m.Var(value=0)
x3 = m.Var(value=0)
x_d = x0-x1
v_d =x2-x3
f_ks = k *(x0-x1)
f_kt = k_t * (x1-0.023)

if linear_damper:
    f_ds = c*v_d
else:
    model_keras = keras.models.load_model('model_81_DVYF_tanh.keras')
    mma = ([-0.83045, -21.0116, 0.0],
           [0.82392, 21.5598, 2.95],
           [-1715.8771],
           [1416.5227])
    f_ds = 4* Gekko_NN_TF(model_keras,mma,m,n_output = 1,activationFxn='tanh').predict([x_d,v_d,2.5])
#
m.Equation(m_s * x2.dt() == -f_ks -f_ds)
m.Equation(m_u * x3.dt() == f_ks - f_kt + f_ds)
m.Equation(x0.dt() == x2)
m.Equation(x1.dt() == x3)
m.options.IMODE = 4
m.options.NODES= 4
m.solve(disp=True)

Scipy model:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from tensorflow import keras
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from scipy import integrate

# import data to init the scaler
df = pd.read_csv("MR dataset/Exp_1/trial_1.csv")
train_x, test_x, train_y, test_y = train_test_split(df[['D','V','Y']], df['F'], test_size=0.2)
train_x = train_x.to_numpy()
test_x = test_x.to_numpy()
train_y = train_y.to_numpy().reshape(-1,1)
test_y = test_y.to_numpy().reshape(-1,1)

input_scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-1, 1))
output_scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-1, 1))
train_x_s= input_scaler.fit_transform(train_x)
train_y_s= output_scaler.fit_transform(train_y)

# Scipy model
f_ds_history=[]
f_ks_history=[]
m_s = 400
m_u = 47.75
k_t = 239e3
k = 22e3
c = 2300
mr_damper_cof = 4
model_keras = keras.models.load_model('model_81_DVYF_tanh.keras')
Non_linear = True
v_history=[]
def ode_rule(t,x):
    x0 = x[0] # m_s displacement
    x1 = x[1] # m_u displacement
    x2 = x[2] # m_s velocity
    x3 = x[3] # m_u velocity
    vol = 2.5
    f_ks = k *(x0-x1)
    f_kt = k_t * (x1-0.023)
    if Non_linear:
        scaled_input =input_scaler.transform(np.array([x0-x1,x2-x3,vol]).reshape(1,-1))
        f_ds_scaled = model_keras.predict(scaled_input)
        f_ds = mr_damper_cof * output_scaler.inverse_transform(f_ds_scaled)[0][0]
    else:
        f_ds = c*(x2-x3)
    
    
    f_ds_history.append(f_ds)
    f_ks_history.append(f_ks)
    v_history.append(x2-x3)
    x0_dot = x2
    x1_dot = x3
    x2_dot = (-f_ks-f_ds)/m_s
    x3_dot = (f_ks+f_ds-f_kt)/m_u
    return np.array([x0_dot,x1_dot,x2_dot,x3_dot])

# solve the ODE
sol = integrate.solve_ivp(ode_rule,(0,5),np.zeros(4),method = 'RK45')

# plot the results
plt.plot(m.time, x0, label='Gekko (linear damper)')
plt.plot(sol.t, sol.y[0],'-.r' , label='Scipy (nonlinear damper (ANN))')

plt.legend()
plt.show()




please let me know what wrong is with my Gekko_NN_TF model?

Without a constraint there may be a non-physical bifurcation of the solution with the initial conditions at 0. Try setting:
x0 = m.Var(value=0,lb=0)

to prevent the non-physical solution. For additional specific support, please include the dependency files so that the Scipy and Gekko solutions are reproducible by someone else.
